# Parse XML from retrofit, android?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit

I have an API which gives me response in SMIL XML format. Below is the format.

```
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/SMIL21/Language">
<head>
<meta name="refreshToken" content="016c71b0cc1e42fa48d576db495a3b2cc97d0b139add2e8fa0138c10351edcf3e76ac961a554"/>
<meta name="startingBitrate" content="2500000"/>
</head>
<body>
<seq>
<par>
<video src="https://tveuniversalkids-vh.akamaihd.net/i/prod/video/506/607/190719_3991003_Trendy_Accent_Wall_Room_Makeover_anvver_1_,25,40,18,12,7,4,2,00.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8?__b__=1000&amp;hdnea=st=1565274657~exp=1565275587~acl=/i/prod/video/506/607/190719_3991003_Trendy_Accent_Wall_Room_Makeover_anvver_1_*~id=316fb474-072e-4efe-a423-614b81ee181c~hmac=253669d278c128e1a88fb94add2687a2dd79c6d7a727d97964626821efff0ead" 
 title="Trendy Accent Wall Room Makeover" abstract="Sequins and glamour are front and center in a  fashion forward space that sisters Lizzie and Caroline design for each other." dur="410000ms" guid="3991003" categories="Series/Get Out of My Room" keywords="Universal Kids,universalkids,Family Entertainment,YouTube Kids,kids,children,what’s new,Get out of my room,get outta my room,get outta my room tv,get out of my room tv,room makeover,kids room makeover" ratings="urn%3Av-chip:tv-g" provider="Universal Kids" type="application/x-mpegURL" height="720" width="1280" clipBegin="0:00">
    <param name="dayPart" value="Primetime"/>
    <param name="entitlement" value="free"/>
    <param name="externalAdvertiserId" value="UNIVERSALKIDS_ANV_3991003"/>
    <param name="fullEpisode" value="false"/>
    <param name="seasonNumber" value="0"/>
    <param name="show" value="Get Out of My Room"/>
    <param name="advertisingGenre" value="Family and Kids"/>
    <param name="programmingType" value="Undefined"/>
    <param name="trackingData" value="aid=2702430253|b=2621440|bc=NBCU-MPAT|ci=1|cid=1573561923689|d=1565274687703|l=410000|mediaPid=oFXMSUI_EEvk|pd=1563557760000|pid=MdbdAekv6_JU|pvid=1014586435510|rid=1573596739926"/>
</video>
<imagestream src="https://tve-static-universalkids.akamaized.net/prod/image/506/607/190719_3991003_Trendy_Accent_Wall_Room_Makeover_anvver_1_1200.fs" width="190" height="107" type="application/filmstrip+json"/>
</par>
</seq>
</body>
</smil>
```

I need to fetch the details in video element but i am not getting the desired output. I think my model class is wrong.

Below is my model class

```
@Root(name = "smil", strict = false)
public class Media {

@Element(name = "src")
@Path("video")
private String videoSrc;

public String getVideoSrc() {
    return videoSrc;
}

@Element(name = "title")
@Path("video")
private String title;

public String gettitle() {
    return title;
}
}
```

Please tell me what am I missing here?

Below is my

```
 public void fetchMedia(String url, Action1<Media> tickerFeedAction1) {

    mediaPlaybackRest.get(url).enqueue(new Callback<Media>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Media> call, Response<Media> response) {
            Observable.just(response.body())
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                    .subscribe(tickerFeedAction1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Media> call, Throwable t) {
            Observable.just((Media) null)
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Observable.empty())
                    .subscribe(tickerFeedAction1);
        }
    });

}
```

Creating the retrofit object from

```
 Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(
                    SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(new 
 Persister(new AnnotationStrategy())))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Comment: "Not getting the desired output"-  what are you getting?

Comment: @GabeSechan i get the response but when I try to get response.body.getVideoSrc() or response.body.gettitle() i get null.

Comment: WHen creating the retrofit object, did you tell it to use an XML converter?  Natively it only supports JSON

Comment: @GabeSechan i am aware of that and using SimpleXmlConverterFactory

Comment: I believe the trick is that  `src` is not an element, it's an attribute. Example for element is the inline `param` List.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what would be the correct model class?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML:

> ```
> <smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/SMIL21/Language">
> <head>
> <meta name="refreshToken" content="016c71b0cc1e42fa48d576db495a3b2cc97d0b139add2e8fa0138c10351edcf3e76ac961a554"/>
> <meta name="startingBitrate" content="2500000"/>
> </head>
> <body>
> <seq>
> <par>
> <video src="
> ```

`src` is not an element. It would be an element if it looked like this:

```
<video>
    <src
```

Which it doesn't, so it is not `@Element`, it is `@Attribute`.

To me, it seems like you should try the following:

```
@Root(name = "smil", strict = false)
public class Media {

    @Attribute(name = "src")
    @Path("body/seq/par/video")
    private String videoSrc;

    public String getVideoSrc() {
        return videoSrc;
    }

    @Attribute(name = "title")
    @Path("body/seq/par/video")
    private String title;
```